# I'm trying to implement a simple library that visualizes touches. I'm at a loss on how to integrate it into my project

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I need to manually import this library into my swift project: https://github.com/morizotter/TouchVisualizer

I'm a relatively new dev and although I have two simple apps under my belt, integrating a library like this with a bunch of new files has been confusing to say the least.

The instructions say to add everything in "/pod" to my project. There is no pod folder, but the "TouchVisualizer" folder seems to have the relevant files (I'm just guessing though since there is no "/pod") I dragged those files into my project and had an info.plist conflict because I already have one, every project does right?

So I erased them and dragged the entire folder into my project and there was no more info.plist conflict. That being said I followed the very first step of using:

```
import TouchVisualizer
```

in my one and only view controller and I got an error saying "no such module".

I would really appreciate any help on what I'm doing wrong, from the GitHub description it seems like its supposed to be simple. But for a someone not familiar with how to import something like this, I'm at a total loss.

Comment: Make a pod folder on the file inspector, copy the touchvisualizer folder inside there. Drag the touch pod folder from the inspector into your project. a new group should be shown.

Comment: Check my answer. I just tried it and it works.

Comment: did you follow these instructions ?
$ gem update
$ gem install cocoapods
then go to your project folder from terminal then,
$ pod init
this will create a file called "Podfile" , open that, then add these lines after this
# Pods for your-project
pod "TouchVisualizer", '~>2.0.1'
then save it and close the xcode. then run this command in terminal
**pod install**
after that you can find a **Pods" fonder and newly created **ur_project.xcworkspace** file. just open that. then you can see 2 project in that workspace. ur project and pods project. you need to work on that .xcworkspace .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really just use cocoa pods as this handles everything for you. But still if you want to manually install it.

1) Download the file from git hub

2) Open it and drag the "TouchVisualizer" folder which is inside the unzipped file you downloaded (NOT the TouchVisualizer-master) into your project making sure you select the "copy" option.

3) This way of "adding" into your project doesn't require you to import a header. Just ignore that step and use the methods directly.

```
    Visualizer.start()
```

*) You only need to import a header in swift when the stuff you want to use is OUTSIDE of your project, like libraries or other stuff.

Comment: thank you for the response! I did what you said about the files. I put the Visualizer.start() in viewDidLoad because I wanted to visualize touches the entire time I'm using the app. I didn't put Visualizer.stop() anywhere, but needless to say when i launched project on my phone there was no visualize indication for touch of any kind.

Comment: you were correct, i just had to add: Visualizer.start() to the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in the app delegate instead of the Viewcontroller itself. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For using this you should first open your pods file.Which is located in the file directory under pods and name should be Podfile.

Then inside it add:

**#TouchVisualizer**

**pod "TouchVisualizer", '~>3.0.0'**

After that open terminal and go to you directory that contain app:
For example if it's Demo in Desktop use command :

**cd ~/Desktop/Demo** 
then in this directory :
**pod install** 
//if you don't want to update old pods 
use : **pod install --no-repo-update**

Wait for update:
Open you file go to your AppDelegate.swift

**import TouchVisualizer**

//You should add the code under  //TouchVisualizer comment for this funcion to start TouchVisualizer on app start.

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, 
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: 
        [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {


    //TouchVisualizer
    //Change config values to true or false for making chanes
    var config = Configuration()
    config.color = UIColor.black
    config.image = UIImage(named: "Your Icon")
    config.showsTimer = true
    config.showsTouchRadius = true
    config.showsLog = true
    Visualizer.start(config)
 }
```

Happy coding.